# Non-isomorphic groups with the same oriented Cayley graph

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory

There are many examples of two non-isomorphic groups with the same Cayley graph. If the graph is non-oriented, asking for the generating set to be minimal does not make the task much harder. However, I was unable to answer the following

$\textbf{Question:}$ Say a set $S$ inside a group is "mag" if it is minimal (for the inclusion) among sets that generate the group ($\textit{i.e.}$ such that the words in $S \cup S^{-1}$ give the full group). Find two non-isomorphic groups $G$ and $H$ such that the oriented Cayley graphs of $G$ and $H$ with respect to $S \subset G$ and $T \subset H$ are isomorphic, given that $S$ and $T$ are "mag".

Apologies in advance if the answer is well-known...

PS: Here by Cayley graph of $G$ w.r.t. $S$, I mean the graph whose vertices are $G$ and $(g,h)$ is an edge if and only if $\exists s \in S, g =hs$. (There are two conventions, but it matters little for the question.) The point being that if $(g,h)$ is an edge then $(h,g)$ need not be one.

PPS: given minimality of $S$ and finiteness of the group, $S$ will usually be anti-symetric.

Here are examples. Take $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $ H= (\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}) *(\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})$. For $H$, picking $ \lbrace a,b \rbrace$ the resulting Cayley graph is going to be infinite unoriented path ("two-way" infinite street). For $G$, you could pick $S =\lbrace 1\rbrace$ or $S = \lbrace -1\rbrace$ but not $S = \lbrace -1, 1\rbrace$. In either case, the resulting (oriented) Cayley graph is going to be a infinite unorientd path ("one-way" infinite street).

There might be two questions: for finite groups and infinite groups. I suspect one could find them more easily by looking at infinite groups.

Comment: Two distinct 2-transitive groups of the same degree will suffice, as both Cayley graphs will be complete graphs. I assume you'd like more interesting examples, though.

Comment: I think I just don't understand your statement. If the resulting graph is complete and $S$ is minimal as said above, then (unless I am mistaken, and this might very well be the case) it means every element is needed to generate the group and also that the product of two (non-trivial) elements should be the identity (otherwise it would mean this element would be generated by others. This forces the group to be $\mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: Sorry, please discard my comment. 

Comment: If $S \cup S^{-1}$ generates the group then so does $S$, right? (In my world the subgroup generated by a given set is the least subgroup that contans it.)

Comment: Thanks for this comment. If the groups are finite (or is infinite, but generated by elements of finite order), then this assumption is indeed superfluous.

I edited the post in order to clarify this point... I forgot to specify that I could not even find a counter-example when the groups are infinite. 

Comment: You talk about the Cayley graphs of $G$ with respect to $S$ and $H$ with respect to $T$ being "identical", but since they are on different vertex sets, they cannot be actually identical. I guess you mean isomorphic rather than identical.

Comment: I was really puzzled by your edit, but I think I know what it's about now. It looks like your 'Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to $S\subset G$' is actually the Cayley graph of the _subsemigroup_ of $G$ generated by $S$? This isn't what one would naturally expect you to mean, given that you have phrased the question as being about Cayley graphs of groups.

Comment: Actually that can't be right, because your definition of the directed Cayley graph is what I would expect it to be. But perhaps you are thinking about generating the group as a semigroup rather than as a group?  (I can't see any reason to do that.) As Andrej says, the subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$ is the smallest subgroup containing $S$ and is therefore the same as the subgroup generated by $S\cup S^{−1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, edited the post ("isomorphic" and "subsemigroup"). I'm not too sure about the phrasing, but the idea is to look at sets $S$ such that the words in $S \cup S^{-1}$ gives the whole group, i.e. that the semigroup $S \cup S^{-1}$ generates is the full group. Next take a minimal element among such sets for the inclusion.

Comment: Right, but 'sets $S$ such that the words in $S\cup S^{-1}$ give the whole group' are just generating sets for the group.  So it seems like it would be more straightforward to define $S\subset G$ to be "mag" if it is a minimal generating set for $G$.  You don't seem to think this is equivalent to what you have written, and I am trying to understand why.

Comment: I guess it's because I am unsure of the meaning different people may have for "generating" and to emphasize the fact that $S$ will often not be symmetric.

Comment: I see.  But then I still don't understand your PPS.  What exactly do you mean by "the one-way line"?  My first comment was based on the idea that perhaps you meant an infinite ray going off in only one direction from the vertex representing the identity.  That would be the Cayley graph of the subsemigroup generated by $S$, and is not the Cayley graph of any group.  But then I thought that can't have been what you meant, since it doesn't satisfy your own definition of the Cayley graph.

Comment: Again, I'm unsure about the terminology, but I meant the infinite oriented path ("one-way", you can only go in one direction?) as opposed to the infinite unoriented path ("two-way", you can go in two directions?).

Comment: Okay, that's what I would have expected you to mean. What you wrote was fine (I think clearer than what you have changed it to). I was just trying to understand why you thought there was some special reason in the infinite case for saying that '$S\cup S^{−1}$ generates $G$', rather than just '$S$ generates $G$'. You are no longer saying that, and so I'm happy. =]

Comment: Well, nearly happy. From your examples it looks like you might actually be using a stronger condition for 'mag' than you have defined. Because by your definition $\{1\}$ and $\{−1\}$ are by no means the only 'mag' generating sets for $\mathbb{Z}$. You can take any set of $n$ relatively prime integers such that the $\gcd$ of any proper subset is not $1$, e.g. $\{6,10,15\}$. So perhaps you are requiring $S$ to have the minimum possible size as well? I wouldn't recommend changing the question though, since it hasn't been answered yet as it stands.

Comment: Good point, that would be an additional question. (I don't remember saying this was the only choice for $\mathbb{Z}$, but sets you could pick...)

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry!  I guess I thought you meant they were the only choices because you said 'the resulting Cayley graph is going to be...', which looked as if you were saying it would _always_ be of that form.
(By the way, I don't agree that there is 'not much choice' of 'mag' generating set for your $H$, or that it has to be symmetric.  Consider $S = \{a,ab\}$ for example, where $a$ and $b$ are the generators of the factors.)

Comment: Once upon a time nodes of a Cayley graph were elements of the group. The more
general graph was a Schreier (coset) graph. Why not now?

Comment: To which graphs are you referring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we consider the dihedral group of order 12, $G = \langle a, b \mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^6 = e \rangle$, then the Cayley graph corresponding to $\{ a, b \}$ is the cyclic graph on 12 vertices with edges labeled alternately by $a$ and $b$.  We may then consider $H_1 = G \times \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ and $H_2 = G \rtimes \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ where the copies of $\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z$ are generated by $c$ and $d$ respectively, and where $d$ acts by $d a d = b$, $d b d = a$. Then the Cayley graph of $H_1$ with respect to $\{ a, b, c \}$ consists of two copies of cyclic graphs of order 12 with edges labeled by $c$ connecting the two graphs.  Since $d$ just interchanges $a$ and $b$ we have that the Cayley graph of $H_2$ with respect to $\{ a, b, d \}$ can be obtained from the Cayley graph of $H_1$ by just relabeling the second copy of the cyclic graph, so that the two Cayley graphs will be isomorphic.

Unfortunately, the generating set for $H_2$ is not minimal since by the definition of $d$ we have $b \in \langle a, d \rangle$.  This can be fixed however by taking two automorphisms $c$ and $d$ which are complicated enough so that this doesn't occur.

Specifically, we can let $c$ act on $G$ by $cac = ababa$, and $cbc = babab$, and we can let $d$ act on $G$ by applying $c$ and then interchanging $a$ and $b$, i.e., $dad = babab$, and $dbd = ababa$.  It's not hard to see that these indeed define order two automorphisms of $G$, and for the same reason as above we have that the Cayley graphs of $H_1$ and $H_2$ will be isomorphic.

It is also not hard to check that we now have $| \langle a, c \rangle | = | \langle b, c \rangle | = 12 < 24$ and $| \langle a, d \rangle | = | \langle a, d \rangle | = 8 < 24$ so that the generating sets are now minimal.  Moreover, the groups $H_1$ and $H_2$ will not be isomorphic, this can be seen for instance by counting the number of elements of order 2, (I counted 15 for $H_1$ and 9 for $H_2$, but I've omitted the tedious details).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of papers I found by googling "nonisomorphic groups with same Cayley digraph":

Morris, J. (1999), Isomorphic Cayley graphs on nonisomorphic groups. Journal of Graph Theory, 31: 345–362.
(Available here: http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~morris/Research/AnneExtension.pdf)

and

Kovács, I. and Servatius, M. (2011), On Cayley digraphs on nonisomorphic 2-groups. Journal of Graph Theory. doi: 10.1002/jgt.20625,

which apparently extends Morris's results.

I haven't looked at these in enough detail to see whether they will answer your question, but it looks like Morris's paper would be a good place to start.

Comment: Clara Loeh has recently submitted a paper on arxiv for the case of finitely generated Abelian groups.   I have not looked at the paper, but suspect it is for undirected graphs.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.27

Comment: Yes, it is for undirected graphs.

Comment: Thanks for the further comments (question corrected) and apologies as I did not have time to look at the papers... My intuition was somehow against Abelian groups being potential counter-examples, but I could easily be wrong.